# Qiskit library.gaussian() does not accept parametric expression

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, quantum-operation

I'm trying to build a gaussian pulse in qiskit where I keep the amplitude as a parameter but for the followig code

```
theta = Parameter('θ')
drive_amps=np.linspace(0.0,0.75,50)

with pulse.build(backend, name='example') as program:
  pulse.set_frequency(fq1,pulse.drive_channel(0))
  dur = 100
  amp = theta
  sig = 20
  gaussian_pulse = library.gaussian(dur, amp, sig)
  pulse.play(gaussian_pulse, pulse.drive_channel(0))
```

I get an error that ParametricExpression cannot be cast as complex. From the documentation it seems that
`gaussian(duration, amp, sigma)` takes the input `(Union[complex, ParameterExpression])` for amp but I have not been able to get the input to work. Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `library.gaussian` to become `library.Gaussian` with capital G.

Qiskit Pulse contains both `qiskit.pulse.library.gaussian` and `qiskit.pulse.library.Gaussian`

`gaussian` is a function with the signature:

```
def gaussian(
    duration: int, amp: complex, sigma: float, name: Optional[str] = None, zero_ends: bool = True
) -> Waveform
```

Note the type of `amp` parameter.

And `Gaussian` is a class whose constructor has the signature:

```
def __init__(
    self,
    duration: Union[int, ParameterExpression],
    amp: Union[complex, ParameterExpression],
    sigma: Union[float, ParameterExpression],
    name: Optional[str] = None,
    limit_amplitude: Optional[bool] = None,
)
```

Again, note the type of `amp` parameter.

As you want to create a parametric pulse, you need the `Gaussian` class not the `gaussian` function!